# ToDo List with node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I have been trying to solve this problem for a week and all to no avail, this is my final test, which must be passed before tomorrow. All semester we studied mostly JS applicable to the browser. And in the last 2 lessons, Node.js + Express was superficially explained to us and this time is not enough to figure it out. If you understand, I would really appreciate your help, as this is a very important test and my final score depends on it, thank you in advance!

For this part I need to

Any duplicated tasks thats on TODO or COMPLETED cannot be added and an alert pops up

Data is still there when the browser is closed, refresh or cleared from local storage

When a task is moved to COMPLETED, the data stays in the same section when refreshed, closed and/or cleared cache

When a task is deleted from COMPLETED it no longer appears and remains deleted even when refresh, closed and/or clear cache

I cannot use LOCAL STORAGE to store input data

```
let taskDatastore = {
    "todo": [
        "finish test 2",
    ],
    "completed": [
        "read the test instructions",
    ],
};

// GET handler returns all tasks to the client
app.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    /*
        Returns 200 with response body containing the datastore
    */
    res.status(200).send(taskDatastore);
});

// POST handler adds a task to a list
app.post('/task', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
const task = req.body.task;

if (taskDatastore.todo.includes(task) || taskDatastore.completed.includes(task)) {
    res.status(400).send({});
} else {
    // send 201 status with no response body
    res.status(201).send({taskDatastore});
}

console.log (req.body.task);
});

    
    /*
        Input: data coming into this handler will be in the form:

        {"task": "mytask"}

        You can see contents of the incoming request with:
        console.log(req.body.task). "req" is the request
        and within it, the property req.body holds the incoming data
        above from the client request, hence "task" is a property of
        that incoming request data object.

        Output: This handler should send the datastore back to
        the client with a 201 response code if successful, and return
        and 400 response code with no response body if the task already
        exists in either the TODO or Completed list.
    */

    /*
        YOUR CODE HERE
    */

    // send 201 status with no response body
    res.status(201).send({})
});

// DELETE handler deletes all tasks in TODO and Completed lists
app.delete('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    /*
        This handler will return 204 status code with an empty
        body when all tasks are deleted from the TODO and Completed
        lists.
    */

    /*
        YOUR CODE HERE
    */

    // send 204 status code with no response body
    res.status(204).send()
});

// DELETE handler deletes a task from the TODO list
// and adds the task to the Completed list
app.delete('/task/todo/:task', (req, res) => {
    /*
        req.params gets a parameter variable
        The :task part of the path indicates
        data is being passed in the URL instead
        of the query or in post data. To get this
        data, you would use `req.params.task`

        This handler will return 204 status code with
        no response body after deleting the task from the
        TODO list and adding the task to the Completed list.
    */

    /*
        YOUR CODE HERE
    */

    // send 204 status code with no response body
    res.status(204).send()
});

// DELETE handler deletes a task the client passes via the URL path
app.delete('/task/completed/:task', (req, res) => {
    /*
        This handler (like the previous handler) will return
        a 204 status code with no response body after it deletes
        the task from the Completed list.
    */

    /*
        YOUR CODE HERE
    */

    // send 204 status code with no response body
    res.status(204).send();
});

// This base handler will serve the HTML page todo.html to localhost:3000 when
// the app is started
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('todo.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: If you can't pass the final test maybe that's the right result?

Comment: @SergeGrandman Welcome to SO. Most of the information you need is already provided to you. If you closely read the comments you will understand what you need to do. For reference on JS, you can always check MDN. Look into array methods as that will be useful for you. All the best for the finals.

Comment: @Dominik No, this is not the correct result, since before this module with Node.js I had 100% result of completion in the browser part of javascript, the problem is that I don't have enough time to figure it out, deadline tomorrow.

Comment: I never had help with any of my finals.